# Removing a node from XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML snippet in an XDocument

```
  <axes dimension="y">
    <axis id="y11" scale="log" label="label1">
      ...
    </axis>
    <axis id="y12" scale="log" label="label1">
      ...
    </axis>
  </axes>
  <axes dimension="x">
    <axis id="x0" label="">
      ...
    </axis>
    <axis id="x1" label="">
      ...
    </axis>
  </axes>
```

This is in an XDocument and I want to remove the y12 axis from it and leave the rest remaining.  So, the final output would be

```
  <axes dimension="y">
    <axis id="y11" scale="log" label="label1">
      ...
    </axis>
  </axes>
  <axes dimension="x">
    <axis id="x0" label="">
      ...
    </axis>
    <axis id="x1" label="">
      ...
    </axis>
  </axes>
```

How can this be done?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
xDocument
   .Elements("axes")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dimension") == "y")
   .Elements("axis")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "y12")
   .Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with an XDocument, not an XElement, you should use the `Root` property in order to get the `Elements` method to work as intended and find elements off the root:

Instead of `xDocument.Elements("axes")...` use:

```
xDocument.Root.Elements("axes")
  .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dimension") == "y")
  .Elements("axis")
  .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "y12")
  .Remove();
```

Alternately, you can skip `Root` by using `Descendants` directly:

```
 xDocument.Descendants("axes")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("dimension") == "y")
   .Elements("axis")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "y12")
   .Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 xDocument.Descendants("axis")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "y12")
   .Remove();
```